# Massive padding in Firefox's URL bar

Tags: firefox

I updated from Firefox 21 to 23 only to find large amounts of vertical padding in the URL bar, as well as significantly increased padding in the tab bar and addon bar. Where are the settings that control this?

[image]

Note this is specifically *not* fixed by the new dpi setting `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`, which changes the size of things but not the relative amount of padding.

Comment: I think it should look this way and there's no option to change it. :\

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the settings in your UserChrome.css [link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css)

Add this code to change those settings as well as the highlighting.

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

.autocomplete-richlistitem { padding-top:2px!important; padding-bottom:2px !important; }
.autocomplete-richlistitem:not(:first-child) { border-top: 1px solid #ddd  !important; }
.autocomplete-richlistitem[selected="true"] { border-top-color:transparent !important; }

*|span.ac-emphasize-text {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,255,255,1)!important;
 background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.2)!important;
}
```